# How to bring ".bashrc" in effect without logging out or Restarting the current session?

Tags: environment-variables, bashrc

I am basically using .bashrc for adding environment variables. Each time I add a new Environment variable, I have to log out the current session and log in again to bring the changes in effect.

Is there any way where I can add environment variable and continue working without restarting the session ?

[I think I am clear with my question. If more information is needed, please let me know]

Any help is highly appreciated. :)

(Ubuntu 14.04 - 32-bit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `source ~/.bashrc`, or `. ~/.bashrc`. Both are the same in bash, and will update you ENV variables.

Example:

```
export $FOO=bar
echo $FOO 
bar
echo "FOO=test" >> ~/.bashrc
. ~/.bashrc
echo $FOO 
test
```

Comment: Few days back I tried "source" but it showed "command not found".
But today it worked like a gem. 

Sometimes ubuntu behaves strangely but still I love it. :D 
Thanks a lot noleti.

Answer (score 0):

If they are terminal releated (like archey or alias commands etc) you can do `exit`. Else you need to relog.