# Cannot see lines added to bashrc in printenv

Tags: bash, environment-variables, bashrc

I am trying to add some lines to my `.bashrc`. I ran these commands:

```
echo "export PATH=$PATH:/home/dr/augustus-3.2.2/bin" >> $HOME/.bashrc
echo "export PATH=$PATH:/home/dr/augustus-3.2.2/script" >> $HOME/.bashrc
echo "export AUGUSTUS_CONFIG_PATH=/home/dr/augustus-3.2.2/config/" >> $HOME/.bashrc
```

Then I ran `printenv`, and I got the following output.

```
dr_hedayati@hedayati:~$ printenv 
XDG_VTNR=7 
SSH_AGENT_PID=1233 
XDG_SESSION_ID=c1 
CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=xim 
SELINUX_INIT=YES 
XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR=/var/lib/lightdm-data/dr_hedayati 
SESSION=ubuntu 
GPG_AGENT_INFO=/run/user/1000/keyring-z3D4T4/gpg:0:1 
XDG_MENU_PREFIX=gnome- 
SHELL=/bin/bash 
VTE_VERSION=3409 
TERM=xterm 
SSH_AGENT_LAUNCHER=upstart 
WINDOWID=56623115 
UPSTART_SESSION=unix:abstract=/com/ubuntu/upstart-session/1000/1173 
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/run/user/1000/keyring-z3D4T4 
GTK_MODULES=overlay-scrollbar:unity-gtk-module 
USER=dr_hedayati 
JRE_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_40/jre 
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=:/home/dr_hedayati/root/lib 
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36: 
XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0 
XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0 
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring-z3D4T4/ssh 
DEFAULTS_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path 
SESSION_MANAGER=local/hedayati:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1283,unix/hedayati:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1283 
XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/usr/share/upstart/xdg:/etc/xdg 
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_40/bin:/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_40/jre/bin:/home/dr_hedayati/Downloads/CEGMArequirment/ncbi-blast-2.2.25+/bin:/home/dr_hedayati/Downloads/hmmer-3.1b2/binaries:/home/dr_hedayati/augustus-3.2.2/bin:/home/dr_hedayati/augustus-3.2.2/scripts:/home/dr_hedayati/Downloads/busco:/usr/local/bin:/home/dr_hedayati/root/bin 
DESKTOP_SESSION=ubuntu 
QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=appmenu-qt5 
JOB=dbus 
PWD=/home/dr_hedayati 
XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus 
JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_40 
LANG=en_US.UTF-8 
GDM_LANG=en_US 
MANDATORY_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path 
UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=1 
IM_CONFIG_PHASE=1 
COMPIZ_CONFIG_PROFILE=ubuntu 
GDMSESSION=ubuntu 
ROOTSYS=/home/dr_hedayati/root 
SESSIONTYPE=gnome-session 
SHLVL=1 
XDG_SEAT=seat0 
HOME=/home/dr_hedayati 
LANGUAGE=en_US 
GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated 
AUGUSTUS_CONFIG_PATH=/home/dr_hedayati/augustus-3.2.2/config/ 
LOGNAME=dr_hedayati 
COMPIZ_BIN_PATH=/usr/bin/ 
QT4_IM_MODULE=xim 
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/ 
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-l14niRgOEt 
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s 
INSTANCE= 
TEXTDOMAIN=im-config 
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000 
DISPLAY=:0 
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity 
GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus 
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s 
TEXTDOMAINDIR=/usr/share/locale/ 
COLORTERM=gnome-terminal 
XAUTHORITY=/home/dr_hedayati/.Xauthority 
_=/usr/bin/printenv
```

why can I not see the lines I added in the `printenv` output?

Comment: unless you have defined it, `$home` isn't what you think it is. Run `echo $home` to see. The variable you wanted is `$HOME`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bring ".bashrc" in effect without logging out or Restarting the current session?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/503244/how-to-bring-bashrc-in-effect-without-logging-out-or-restarting-the-current-s)

Comment: what i do to solve it? when i open .bashrc using gedit, i can see added lines but it is no same line in "printenv" output. i am beginner in linux and need to your kindly helps

Answer (score 3):

Because you have to source .bashrc first:

```
. .bashrc
```

This will read the content of . bashrc into your environment. Alternatively, you can close the terminal and open a new.